Is there a way to customize the behavior of Ctrl + Delete in VS Code?
Is there a way to customize the behavior of Ctrl + Delete in VS Code so that when there is exactly one space after the cursor, only the space is deleted instead of the space and the following word?
For example, given the following text:
"[Cursor Position] Hello"

Currently, when pressing  Ctrl + Delete, if there is exactly one space between the cursor and the word, it deletes the space along with the word. However, I would like it to only delete the space in this case.
In situations where there are two or more spaces, the behavior works as expected and deletes the spaces first before the word.
Is there any way to achieve this behavior in VS Code?

From Shortcut ctrl+del doesn't delete trailing space.
Make this keybinding in your keybindings.json:
{
  "key": "ctrl+delete",
  "command": "deleteWordStartRight"
}

That will override the usual behaviour of deleteWordRight that is normally bound to ctrl+delete.
